# Using wget in python (Error Code Help me)

Tags: python

Heres my code.

```
import os, sys
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
     sys.exit(1)

h = os.popen("wget -r %s") % sys.argv[1]
fil = open("links.txt","w")
dir = os.listdir("%s") % sys.argv[1]

for file in dir:
     print file.replace("@","?")
     fil.write("%s/"+file.replace("@","?")) % sys.argv[1]
     fil.write("\n")
h.close()
```

running the it, like this python project.py http://google.com

gives me error code.

```
1.py:5 RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didnt return -1 or -2 for exception
h = os.popen("wget -r %s") % sys.argv[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py" line 5, in <module>
h = os.popen("wget -r %s") % sys.argv[1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type<s> for %: 'file' and 'str'
```

What are im going wrong. (Still learning python) Any solution/ tip?

I dont explain the code, i think you understand what im trying to do

Answer (score 9):

1. h = os.popen("wget -r %s" % sys.argv[1])
2. use the subprocess module, os.popen is obsolete
3. python has urllib, you can consider using that to have pure python code
4. there is pycurl

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
h = os.popen("wget -r %s" % sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the `%` operator in the wrong place: you need to put it directly after the format string:

```
h = os.popen("wget -r %s" % sys.argv[1])
...
dir = os.listdir("%s" % sys.argv[1])
...
fil.write(("%s/"+file.replace("@","?")) % sys.argv[1])
```

Alternatively, since you're just using `%s`, just do plain and simple string concatenation:

```
h = os.popen("wget -r " + sys.argv[1])
...
dir = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
...
fil.write(sys.argv[1] + "/" + file.replace("@","?"))
```